# Ubuntu 14.04 installer doesn't show existing partitions

Tags: installation, partitioning, multi-boot, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7. I have a 500 GB hard disk split into 3 partitions. I am installing Ubuntu from a live USB drive. But I am stuck at the "Installation type" stage. This is what I see:

[image]

My three partitions aren't shown. What do I do?

Comment: I bet that's an UEFI/GPT problem.

Comment: So, could you please help

Comment: Related question on AskUbuntu: [“Install alongside” option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using “Something Else”?](http://askubuntu.com/q/163962/40581)

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem. Opening terminal and running the command

```
sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
```

indicated that I have both MBR and GPT tables present. This happened because I had originally Windows 8 pre-installed on my computer. Windows 8 uses GPT scheme. I installed windows 7 over it. Windows 7 is using MBR and finally my disk end up being MBR with some stray GPT data on it.

This is a known problem and can be fixed using FixParts

```
fixparts /dev/sda
```

The program will detect the problem automatically and propose solution. More details [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) if you're interested.

The program is readily available within Ubuntu 14.04 live usb.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem for me! Two comments though: 1) `fixparts` requires root access so I had to run it with `sudo`. 2) I have multiple HDs (one SSD & one data drive) so I had to run `fixparts` for both `sda` and `sdb`.

Comment: I am having the when installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1. It is a similar case. gdisk shows both MBR and GPT. When I ran fixparts, it says that some GPT signatures were detected that were probably leftovers from a previous operating system. If I delete them, is there any risk of losing my data in windows? I already created a 40GB partition in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is to ascertain whether you disk has an all-new GPT partition table, or an old-style one. You should boot Ubuntu, choose *Try Ubuntu without installing it*, open a terminal, and issue this command:

```
  sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

If this command generates output about being unable to read/access the disk partition table, then you have a GPT-kind partition table. In this case, the command

```
  sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
```

should instead produce a meaningful output, without any complaint about an *MBR*. This is to confirm that you have a GPT partition table. If you do, you will find help [on the Ubuntu Help pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Answer (score 2):

How to fix this issue with Ubuntu 14.04:

1. Log on Windows
2. Download AOMEI Partition Assistant
3. Create a new partition
4. Convert it to EXT3
5. Start again the ubuntu installation
6. It works.

Answer (score 1):

I think your hard disk is converted to dynamic. You can verify that with Windows built in Disk management.

Now you need to convert your disk from dynamic to basic with help of the [How to Convert a Dynamic Disk to a Basic Disk](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html) article on SevenForums. (I used minitool partition wizard PROFESSIONAL EDITION). I did not loose any data in this procedure. That did the trick. I faced another problem in the installation which may or may not be related. Still sharing the link: [Rod's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/407152) on *Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition when installing Ubuntu from USB* at AskUbuntu is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I Just converted my Disk from MBR to GPT and my problem solved.
I used "AOMEI Partition Assistant" application for converting my Disk to GPT.

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little to explain how to accomplish this?  You mention the general approach to the solution and a tool you used, but not how to actually solve the problem.  Thanks.