# ubuntu 14.04.1 installer doesnt detect any partitions, even after fixparts corrected partition table

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, installation

Trying to install 14.04 LTS alongside Windows 7 I have four partitions (2 windows partitions), a ext4 for the ubuntu install, and a remaining ntfs data partition

As a follow up to [Ubuntu 14.04 installer doesn't show existing partitions](https://superuser.com/questions/744916/ubuntu-14-04-installer-doesnt-show-existing-partitions) I encounter a very similar problem. Running fixparts however does not indicate any particular problem with the partition table.

Whatever I try to do, I always end up with an empty list in the installer and cannot choose anything to install /root to...

Comment: The solution is in the answer to this question! http://askubuntu.com/questions/486556/no-partitions-found-while-installing-dual-boot-win8-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: If you wanted to install Ubuntu along with windows, you have to create an unallocated partition space. Remove the ext4 and try installing in that un allocated space. Make sure it has minimum 20GB of space

Answer (score 0):

the drives might be encrypted and/or the ubuntu default drivers do not have your hard drive controller.  I had the same issue when using RAID on my desktop with windows 7 a few years ago, the windows 7 disk did not have the raid controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it. Cut the cord and go with Ubuntu. I was Windows Network Admin. and troubleshooter for 15 years. If you want to use Ubuntu, go for it and forget Windows. You are asking for trouble. I am definitely not saying it can't be done because it can. But, I have better things to do than chase down Windows errors. I replaced desktop that had Windows with Ubuntu Linux and got a Macbook Pro for portable. The computer should work for you not the other way around.

Comment: yes obviously you are right but the thing is certain software companies still nowadays won't be bothered to provide a GUI under Linux. I am also fed up with the trouble I am having running windooooooze using a VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a bit more the answer was already formulated in this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/486556/no-partitions-found-while-installing-dual-boot-win8-ubuntu-14-04

Using the procedure described in the first answer there, helped me clean up the partition table (by first booting into a Live GParted). Using    fixparts    for some reason didnt clean up all the remaining GPT data but actually turned MBR into GPT.

gdisk did the trick